# Keycloak and Google: auth flow doubts

Tags: rest, react-native, keycloak, google-authentication, ambassador

We have a Spring Boot Web Application serving some REST API and the client consuming these API is a mobile app developed in React Native.

Now we need to secure the APIs and we're going to use Keycloak with Google as Identity Provider.
The integration between Keycloak and Google auth it seems pretty straight forward but I'm not able to understand the entire flow among parts and how to join the Browser login (on Keycloak page that redirects to Google authentication) in order to get a valid access token to perform API calls from mobile app.

I'll try to exaplain in another way, I supposed that:

- Mobile app shows a web page (with Its browser) in order to perform the Keycloak login.
- The end user using the mobile app press the Google button on Keycloak web page and begin redirect to Google for the authentication.
- Google authentication the user and send a redirect URI with identity token and access token to the browser
  ...
  then 
  ... 
  is it correct to get the access token from the URI and use it form the subsequent API calls?
  Is it supposed to work in this way?

I have to say that We also have and API Gateway (Ambassador) in front of our Web Application (containerized in a Kubernetes cluster).

I read different articles online but I'm still confused with the best approch.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: did you find any solution? I am having the same issue

Comment: @Shamim sorry no because we used Keycloack instead of Google ad IDP.

Comment: Yeah, but I am surprised that the keycloak is creating a user for a google account, and event we assign the role to that user we're not able to access the api