# google authentication with keycloak

Tags: keycloak

We are in the process of adding Keycloak for our microservices authentication method.
What we want to achieve is the client application to use the developer's google credentials and keycloack to authenticate them to use the microservice/rest application.
We have managed so far to enable google authentication to our keycloak site.
The problem we are facing is that we cant find a way to call the keycloak api using the google credentials.
We have been reading the keycloack [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62173281/keycloak-and-google-auth-flow-doubts) but it doesnt seem to solve our case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to achive is not possible with Keycloak. You will need to use a Keycloak-specific bearer token to authenticate with the Keycloak REST API.

What you can try in your case is something called a "token exchange". You need to authenticate with google first and get a token from google. This is called an "external token" in Keycloak. Then you may exchange that external token to a Keycloak-specific token (called an "internal token").

Check out the docs for [External to Internal token exchange](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/14.0/securing_apps/#external-token-to-internal-token-exchange).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How would i authenticate with google? I am guessing i will have to create an auth api key on google dashboard and use that, right?

Comment: Sorry, I am not an expert when it comes to Google APIs, but maybe this helps: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server

Comment: Thanks, I have seen that link, but i got completely confused. I am still trying to figure things out. thanks